# What is the function of word "wind" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The context is in the headline of the NY Times:

"Tropical storm Henri winds uncertain path toward Northeast"

the way I interpret this is like, "winds a path to somewhere" does that make any sense?

Comment: Yes. It is a metaphorical use, implying that the path is twisted and winding rather than straight.

Answer (score 1):

Note that ***wind*** pronounced as /waɪnd/ is a verb that means

> ***to turn or cause something to turn***:
>
> - She *wound* the handle but nothing happened. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wind))

So this title probably means that *the tropical storm Henri turned its course toward Northeast*.

Comment: But that use doesn't make sense with a path as object. This is a metaphorical extension.

Comment: Can it not cause the path to turn? Yes, metaphorically.

Comment: to wind a handle is not like the path of the storm winds though the Caribbean.